# how to match cells that contains specific text and color code them in excel

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, spreadsheet

I have a table as below and I would like to color the cell which contains "Failed" to red color. How can I do it in excel?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You need [conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f)

For Excel 2016:

Select the range you want to apply the formatting to, then go to `Home -> Conditional Formatting -> Highlight Cells Rules -> Text that Contains...`

[image]

Enter "Failed" into the box and select your desired formatting. It will also preview this in Excel for you

[image]

The result:

[image]